# Pgbouncer mismatch between 'show pools' and pg_stat_activity

Tags: pgbouncer

If I do 'show servers', it comes back with something like 40 results. If I connect to the database at the same time and do a count of connections using pg_stat_activity (only counting connections to pgbouncer), it comes back with something like 85 connections. I thought those counts should match. What am I misunderstanding? CentOS 7, Pgbouncer 1.8.1, Postgresql 9.6.10.